# Creating hyperlinks in Google App Engine using Jinja2 template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hyperlink, jinja2

I'm trying to scrape links from a RSS page from Quora, which I have been successful in doing so. However, I want those links to appear as hyperlinks in my application, instead of simply appearing as plain text.

Here's the application so far:

http://deploymentapp.appspot.com/

Here's the main python code:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db
import urllib2
import re

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        content = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/rss').read()
        allTitles =  re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>')
        allLinks = re.compile('<link>(.*?)</link>')
        list = re.findall(allTitles,content)
        linklist = re.findall(allLinks,content)
        self.render('frontrss.html', list = list, linklist = linklist)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

here's the HTML source code:

```
<h1>Quora Live Feed</h1><br><br><br>

{% extends "rssbase.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for e in range(1, 19) %}
        {{ (list[e]) }} <br>
        {{ (linklist[e]) }}
        <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

So basically, I don't know how to make the links appear as hyperlinks when scraped from an outside source code in Jinja2 template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic HTML: you put the link inside the `href` attribute of an `a` tag:

```
<a href="{{ linklist[e] }}">{{ list[e] }}</a>
```